# Add a smooth scrolling effect when you click on an image

Tags: html, css, smooth-scrolling

I want to add a smooth scrolling effect when you click on an image. But using "scroll-behavior: smooth;" doesn't work properly. When I add it to the "html" tag in CSS it will also smooth scroll down when reloading the page, when I add it to any other tag it doesn't do anything. How do I fix this?

Code: HTML:

```css
.scrolling-box {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-box">
  <section id="textimage4">
    <h2>
      Meer weten?
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section id="image4">
    <a href="#learnmore" class="scrolling-box">
      <img src="file:///C:/Users/Joost/Desktop/Website/Images/Pijl%203.gif" witdh="200px" height="200px" alt="Arrow down" />
    </a>
  </section>
  <div id="learnmore">
    <section id="image5">
      <img src="file:///C:/Users/Joost/Desktop/Profielfoto.jpg" width="25%" height="25%" alt="Photo me" />
    </section>
    <section id="whoami">
      <p>
        Hoi, ik ben Joost!
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS property:

```
html {
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: That works but as I mentioned, if I do that than if I reload the page it will automatically scroll down.